# Декоратор в python, мини вопрос

Tags: python, декоратор

Допустим вот такой пример:

```
def wrap(f):
    def newf(*args):
        return f(*args)
    return newf

@wrap
def fun(a,b,c):
    print("Hello")

fun(a=1,b=2,c=3) #не работает, а нужно, чтоб работало
```

как такое реализовать? В `newf` указано `*args`, он не знает ни про какие `a,b,c`

Но если я напишу другую `fun2(d,e)` вместо fun вызову `fun2(d=5,e=6)`, тоже должно работать

Answer (score 6):

Используйте `**kwargs`

```
def wrap(f):
    def newf(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return newf

@wrap
def fun(a,b,c):
    print("Hello")

fun(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

Подробнее про синтаксис с `**` можно прочитать, например, здесь

https://djangofan.ru/args-kwargs-python

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что вы написали декоратор для неименованных параметров (кортеж), а потом вызываете функцию с помощью словаря:

```
fun(a=1,b=2,c=3)
# то же самое что и:
fun(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
# а ваш декоратор примает только:
fun(*(1, 2, 3))
```

С помощью вашего декоратора допустимы следующие варианты:

```
def wrap(f):
    def newf(*args):
        print("@", args)
        return f(*args)
    return newf

@wrap
def fun1(a, b, c):
    print("Hello" + str(a+b+c))

@wrap
def fun2(a, b, c=3):
    print("Hello" + str(a+b+c))

@wrap
def fun3(a, b=2, c=3):
    print("Hello" + str(a+b+c))

fun1(*(1, 2, 3))
fun2(*(1, 2))
fun3(*(1,))
```

Чтобы функция с декоратором могла принимать и кортежи и словари используйте:

```
def wrap(f):
    def newf(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return newf
```